# How to override webapi.xml in custom module?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I want to override `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/webapi.xml` file in my custom module.

```
<route url="/V1/categories" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface" method="getTree" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::categories" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

My module path for this webapi is 
`/app/code/CustomModule/Catalog/etc/webapi.xml`

I want to override this specific code.

```
 <!-- Category Product Links -->
    <route url="/V1/categories/:categoryId/products" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface" method="getAssignedProducts" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

**I tried but it still gives me error**

> 

```
{
    "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Catalog::categories, anonymous"
    },
    "trace": "#0 /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/
webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(68):
```

> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator->checkPermissions()\n#1
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(86):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator->validate()\n#2
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(322):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n#3
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(239):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#4
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#5
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#6
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#7
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#8
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#9
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#10
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#11
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#12
>   {main}" }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that you need to make different route url for that specific API

```
  <!-- Category Product Links -->
    <route url="/V1/rbcategories/:categoryId/products" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface" method="getAssignedProducts" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Route url is changed to `<route url="/V1/rbcategories/:categoryId/products" method="GET">`

it will work.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the accepted answer: the reason why merging your custom xml config over the existing one does not produce the desired effect is because `ref` is the `idAttribute`for `<resource>` nodes, and so what the xml merger does is *append* the new node to the list of `<resources>`

Comment: thank you for more clarification :)