# How to override vendor/Magento/Module-customer/etc/webapi.xml

Tags: magento2, overrides, customer-account, webapi

To prevent spammers to create accounts in `Magento 2.2.4`.

**I want to change resource ref= in**

```
 vendor/Magento/Module-customer/etc/webapi.xml
```

How can I override this core `xml` ??

Comment: Here already answered. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238045/how-to-override-webapi-xml-in-custom-module

Answer (score 0):

```
 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/webapi.xml
```

***override module path for this webapi is***

```
/app/code/CustomModule/Catalog/etc/webapi.xml
```

Comment: Do mean /app/code/CustomModule/Customer/etc/webapi.xml ?
 Because I want to change the webapi for the create customer account ?

Comment: @ReneDonkers Yes override webapi.xml in your custom module and make change what you want